# What are the speeds of the windshield wipers on an A320?

Tags: aircraft-systems, airbus-a320

In the Airbus A320, the overhead panel wiper selector knob has three settings: Off, Slow and Fast. At what speed do the wipers operate in Slow and Fast mode?

Comment: To confirm, you are not asking about airspeed, but about the angular speed of the wiper blades themselves?  I doubt this information is published anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

The A320's manual doesn't say—it doesn't have to as what is adjusted is the tension. Assuming you're asking out of curiosity and a general answer / other jet-liners would do:

It's measured in sweeps/strokes (or cycles) per minute – a cycle is two sweeps/strokes. Generally it's 250 sweeps per minute, and the slow mode is 2/3 of that (that's how the [typical control system](https://patents.google.com/patent/US5404085A/en) is designed).

This perfectly matches the numbers for the Boeing 737 ([b737.org.uk](http://www.b737.org.uk/ngata30.htm)) and Airbus A380 (technical training manual). Given the similarity between the 737 and A380, it should be similar if not exact. The optional intermittent option adds a delay between cycles.